# Burn the quiz tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [quiz](/questions/tagged/quiz) tag seems like a meta-tag to me, can we burn it?

Comment: @Servy Burnination is the process of removing them.  You're thinking of "nuking".

Comment: @casper I just tried to imagine what that sentence must sound like to an outsider. Maybe all our critics are right and we *are* nuts. Ah well....

Comment: @Pekka웃 I thought that was a well established fact...

Comment: Note that there isn't a button that can remove a tag from all questions, at least not for moderators.  The community leaders might have such a button, but they prefer the questions be reviewed by the community individually, since many questions with bad tags also have other problems.

Comment: And from what I remember of that tag there were quite a few spam bait questions.

Comment: Soooo... When do we start? I haven't burninated something for a long time!

Comment: @Undo I *think*, go through the questions: either close/delete or edit out "quiz". I've removed maybe 20 so far

Comment: @hayden I can't close yet, but almost! ~2650. Come on, upvotes! I'll start some editing.

Comment: @Undo you can also flag to close questions too if it makes sense to (which just sends it to the close vote queue)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Burninate: quiz](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192925/burninate-quiz)