# Burninate: quiz

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

We have a [quiz](/questions/tagged/quiz) tag.  A lot of the questions in it are either on hold or closed, and [only a handful of them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bquiz%5D+is%3Aquestion+score%3A1) have a positive score.  (Even then, from my quick glance, they seem like they're off-topic for SO anyway.)

It doesn't seem like it's a tag that could survive on its own - most questions are about *creating* some sort of quiz.  Unless I'm missing something here, can we call in the Trodgor brigade on this one?

Comment: To be fair there are 210 questions with that tag, 73 have a score of 1 or higher, 105 of a score of 0 and only 32 have a score of -1 or lower.

Comment: **+1** It's a meta tag, burn it!

Comment: Some of them seem to be tagged with [tag:multiple-choice], which doesn't look encouraging to my eyes, either.

Comment: Oh, this one is going down.  Shouldn't take but a minute or two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]
                              Burned.

However, it seems to want to come back.  Perhaps blacklisting?

Comment: I put it on my list of now *76* tags that will be kept dead.

Comment: @charles I think I love you, so what am I so afraid of?

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not sure of a tag there is no cure for...